# Decoding a primitive serial protocol in c#

Tags: c#, serial-port, protocols, binary-data

I grew up with C in the 80's but a complete beginner in c# and object oriented programming so some of you may have a good laugh at this.

I am trying to write a simple application to decode telemetry data from a lab instrument. I plan to write the final code using Windows Forms for look and feel but I made an experimental implementation of the core mechanics as a console app.

The data stream contain 72 byte messages starting with 0x55 0x2f 0x48, then contains payload data and ends with a checksum. I want to "catch" these messages, discard those with bad checksums and decode parts of the payload for display.

The test app work well but simply prints the incoming data. (Although because of its primitive design it does of course take 0x55 in the payload as the start of a new message)

What would be the best practice here? Should I put a state machine into the event handler for the serial port or have a timer that periodically checks the input buffer? I am actually not even sure how to access to the incoming data "outside" the event handler. Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

The code of my experimental app is this:

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace Serial_port_experiment_console 
{
    class Program 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            var enable_telemetry = new byte[] { 0x55, 0x92, 4, 0x15 };
            var disable_telemetry = new byte[] { 0x55, 0x91, 4, 0x16 };

            SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("COM12", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            sp.Open();

            sp.Write(enable_telemetry, 0, enable_telemetry.Length); // Start telemetry

            sp.DataReceived += port_OnReceiveData;

            Console.ReadLine(); // Wait for keyboard RETURN before closing program

            sp.Write(disable_telemetry, 0, disable_telemetry.Length); // Stop telemetry

            sp.Close();
        }

        private static void port_OnReceiveData(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) 
        {
            SerialPort spL = (SerialPort)sender;
            byte[] buf = new byte[spL.BytesToRead];
            spL.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            foreach (Byte b in buf) 
            {
                if (b == 0x55) { Console.WriteLine(); } // Start of a new report
                Console.Write(b.ToString("X")); // Write the hex code
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have to query the device for data or does the device emit new data constantly? If so what is the interval?

Comment: It sends the messages constantly with 10ms gaps

Answer (score 2):

Some encapsulation would help you - I would separate the logic of the reading from the port from the actual line processing into a couple of classes. Something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting reading data");
    var reader = new LinesReader();
    Console.WriteLine("Reading data...");

    try
    {
        reader.Start();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    finally
    {
        reader.Stop();
    }

    foreach (var line in reader.ValidLines)
    {
        line.DoSomethingWithBytes();
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}

internal sealed class LinesReader
{
    private static readonly byte[] EnableCode = new byte[] { 0x55, 0x92, 4, 0x15 };
    private static readonly byte[] DisableCode = new byte[] { 0x55, 0x91, 4, 0x16 };
    private readonly SerialPort sp;
    private readonly List<LineInput> lines = new List<LineInput>();

    public LinesReader()
    {
        sp = new SerialPort("COM12", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        lines.Add(new LineInput());
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        sp.DataReceived += DataReceived;
        sp.Open();

        // Start telemetry
        sp.Write(EnableCode, 0, EnableCode.Length);
    }

    private void DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        LineInput current;
        byte[] buf = new byte[sp.BytesToRead];
        sp.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

        for (int offset = 0; offset < buf.Length; )
        {
            current = GetCurrentLine();
            offset = current.AddBytes(offset, buf);
        }
    }

    private LineInput GetCurrentLine()
    {
        if (lines.Count == 0 || lines[lines.Count - 1].IsComplete)
        {
            var ret = new LineInput();
            lines.Add(ret);
            Console.WriteLine($"Starting line {lines.Count}");
            return ret;
        }
        return lines[lines.Count - 1];
    }

    public IEnumerable<LineInput> ValidLines => lines.Where(e => e.IsValid);

    public void Stop()
    {
        // Stop telemetry
        sp.Write(DisableCode, 0, DisableCode.Length);

        sp.DataReceived -= DataReceived;

        sp.Close();
    }
}

internal sealed class LineInput
{
    private readonly List<byte> bytesInLine = new List<byte>();
    public static byte StartCode { get; } = 0x55;

    public bool IsComplete { get; private set; }

    public void DoSomethingWithBytes()
    {
        //Here I'm just printing the line.
        Console.WriteLine(bytesInLine);
    }

    public bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            if (!IsComplete) return false;
            //TODO - checksum (return true if checksum correct)
            return true;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds bytes until the end of the array or a 0x55 code is read
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bytes"></param>
    /// <returns>The new offset to start the next segment at.</returns>
    public int AddBytes(int offset, byte[] bytes)
    {
        int bytePosition = offset;
        while (bytePosition < bytes.Length)
        {
            var currentByte = bytes[bytePosition];
            if (currentByte == StartCode)
            {
                IsComplete = true;
                break;
            }
            bytesInLine.Add(currentByte);
            bytePosition++;
        }
        return bytePosition;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this was really interesting however does not not suffer from identifying 0x55 in the payload as the start of a new message just like my experimental code? Also, in my case, DoSomethingWithBytes would probably update some progress bars and labels in a WIndows Form, how do I access the received data inside that function?

Comment: I meant to say "does it not suffer". To make it robust I would prefer to identify the entire sequence 0x55 0x2f 0x48 that precedes the payload.

Answer (score 1):

It probably isn't best practice to put all the logic in the event handler. I would suggest that `port_OnReceiveData` should only be concerned with extracting the 72 byte message. Then you might have another method (or possibly another class) which accepts this message and parses it and extracts whatever data it contains and then in turn may pass that data to another method or class for further processing or saving to a database etc.

I would start by developing `port_OnReceiveData` to reliably capture the incoming messages. I think you should check for sequence 0x55 0x2f 0x48 rather than just 0x55. Presumably 0x55 could also appear anywhere in the payload, not just the start. Can you contact the manufacturer of the device (or check their website) for details of the message protocol?

A serial port is a difficult thing to test so the idea would be to limit the amount of code dependent on the SerialPort logic so that you can test the actual code you care about (i.e. the processing of the message) in isolation. For instance, once you have captured a few of the 72 byte messages you can keep them and use them to develop your unit tests and logic for the code that will parse these messages without your PC or Laptop having to be physically connected to the lab device.

Another thing you can do if you really want to test your logic is to create a virtual serial port and transmit *known* data. This technique can be used to ensure your logic is capturing the message correctly. For instance, I once had to read data from a variety of medical devices including a heart rate monitor. I then had to plot this data on a graph. It is obviously crucial that this be correct. I created a test app that generated known wave patterns: a sin wave, saw tooth wave, flat line etc all of known amplitudes and frequencies. I created a virtual com port pair and my test app sent this test wave form data into the com port using the same serial port message format as the real device and I was able to validate that the data I captured and output on the screen was identical to my known wave forms.

Comment: Thanks. I did use com0com to connect my test code to another program I wrote that generated know data. I agree with your suggestion to limit the event handler to a minimum of logic but my problem is that I am not sure how to to access earlier received bytes within the event handler. Ideally I would like some kind of queue that start building when I receive 0x55 and then if I also receive 0x2f and 0x48 it will collect the payload (and thus ignore new occurences of 0x55) and then end after 72 received bytes, calculate the checksum and then make the content available to the parent process.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use a ```Queue```. When a message comes in it should be immediately added to the queue. You would then have another thread or process that read message off the queue and processed them accordingly. 10ms is very frequent so depending on how long your processing logic takes you could end up becoming ever more out of step with the 'live' data. This may or may not be an issue for you.

Comment: You are probably right. I have also heard about a Readasync function that is supposed to be helpful for this type of communications. Since it's 9600bps there is about 93ms between messages. I have already seen that the event handler for received data does not trigger on every byte but often reads two or three.

Comment: @BjörnEkelund you can set this with ```_incomingSerialPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1;``` or did you mean even with this set it still reads more than 1 byte?

Comment: I have not actively set that so I assume it is 1. Yes I see reads of more than 1 byte. My event handler is written to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

I found the question interesting, so whipped up a quick example of what I'd (somewhat naively, without too much planning) do in this case. 
Pretty idiomatic C#. Something (MySerialMessageReader) is responsible for reading the data, and fires off an event with a nicely parsed message for the consumer to react to.

Hope that helps?

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var reader = new MySerialMessageReader())
        {
            reader.MessageReaceived += (s, e) =>
            {
                // TODO: Process message / react to it. Probably put it in a queue to be processed
                Console.WriteLine("Received a new message: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message.Data));
            };

            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for data from serial port...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

class MySerialMessageReader : IDisposable
{
    private byte[] mBuffer = new byte[72];
    private int mReceivedCount = 0;
    private bool mIsReadingMessage;

    SerialPort mPort = new SerialPort("COM12", 9600, Parity.None);

    public event EventHandler<MessageEventArgs> MessageReaceived;

    public MySerialMessageReader()
    {
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        mPort.DataReceived += Port_DataReceived;
        mPort.Open();
    }

    private void Port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.EventType == SerialData.Eof)
        {
            if (mIsReadingMessage && mReceivedCount < Message.MESSAGE_LENGTH)
            {
                Debug.Fail("Received EOF before an entire message was read.");
                return;
            }
        }

        // Put the read buffer into our cached buffer
        int n = 0;
        while (n < mPort.BytesToRead)
        {
            var readByte = (byte)mPort.ReadByte();

            if (!mIsReadingMessage && readByte == 0x55)
            {
                mIsReadingMessage = true; // New start of message
            }

            if (mIsReadingMessage)
            {
                // We're reading a message, put the message into a temporary buffer
                // whilst we read(/wait for) the rest of the message
                mBuffer[mReceivedCount++] = (byte)mPort.ReadByte();
            }

            if (mReceivedCount == Message.MESSAGE_LENGTH)
            {
                // We've got enough to construct a message
                Message m = null;
                if (Message.TryParse(mBuffer, ref m))
                {
                    if (this.MessageReaceived != null)
                        this.MessageReaceived(this, new MessageEventArgs(m));
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid message received. Checksum error?");
                }

                mReceivedCount = 0;
                Array.Clear(mBuffer, 0, 72);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (mPort != null)
        {
            mPort.DataReceived -= Port_DataReceived;
            mPort.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

class Message
{
    private const int CHECKSUM_LENGTH = 3;
    private const int START_INDICATOR_LENGTH = 3;
    public const int MESSAGE_LENGTH = 72;

    public byte[] Data;
    public byte[] Checksum;

    private Message(byte[] data, byte[] checkSum)
    {
        this.Data = data;
        this.Checksum = checkSum;
    }

    public static bool TryParse(byte[] data, ref Message message)
    {
        if (data.Length != MESSAGE_LENGTH)
            return false; // Unexpected message length

        if (data[0] != 0x55 || data[1] != 0x2F || data[2] != 0x48)
            return false; // Invalid message start

        var withotStartIndicator = data.Skip(START_INDICATOR_LENGTH);

        var justData = withotStartIndicator.Take(MESSAGE_LENGTH - START_INDICATOR_LENGTH - CHECKSUM_LENGTH).ToArray();
        var justChecksum = withotStartIndicator.Skip(justData.Length).ToArray();

        // TODO: Insert checksum verification of justChecksum here
        // TODO: parse justData into whatever your message look like
        message = new Message(justData, justChecksum);

        return true;
    }
}

class MessageEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Message Message { get; set; }

    public MessageEventArgs(Message m)
    {
        this.Message = m;
    }
}
```

Edit: You can obviously take this as far as you'd like, with `async`, queues, and whatever have you. But if you're not reading *too* much data, it's not such a bad thing to do it all in the event handler (in my opinion).

Comment: Wow! I am so grateful. Here at the office I can't test it but I will when I get back home tonight. From what I can see you have solved what I found problematic; how to address/access the buffered read data and identifying a sequence of several bytes.